# Match content inside brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a good regex that works well for most my cases:

```
"\(.*\)"
```

This regex matches nested brackets which is good: "ABC **( DEF (GHI) JKL )** MNO"

But there is a tricky case: "This is ABC **(XXX) DEF (XXX) (XXX)**". As you can see this regex matches also DEF, but it doesn't.

Any ideas of how I can adjust my regex?

Comment: If recursion works in C# realization of  regex - `\(((?R)|[^\(\)])+\)`

Comment: It shows an error - http://prntscr.com/i27syy

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't insist* on *regular expressions* you can put a simple *stack-based* implementation:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateEnclosed(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    yield break;

  Stack<int> positions = new Stack<int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char ch = value[i];

    if (ch == '(')
      positions.Push(i);
    else if (ch == ')') 
      if (positions.Any()) {
        int from = positions.Pop();

        if (!positions.Any()) // <- outmost ")"
          yield return value.Substring(from, i - from + 1);
      }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
// Let's combine both examples into one and elaborate it a bit further:
string test = "ABC (DEF (GHI) J(RT(123)L)KL) MNO (XXX1) DEF (XXX2) (XXX3)";

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, EnumerateEnclosed(test)));
```

Outcome:

```
(DEF (GHI) J(RT(123)L)KL)
(XXX1)
(XXX2)
(XXX3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `\([^)]+\)[^(]+\)|\([^)]+\)`

**Details**:

`[^(]` Match a single character not present in the list "("

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

`|` or

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/424EhV/1)